# 1920x1280 retina monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I’m looking for a large monitor for my MacBook (2019 Intel 16”). Huawei sells a 3,840 x 2,560 monitor instead of the usual 3,840 x 2,160, which is the largest monitor at a reasonable price (less than £600, and nobody sells 5k anymore).

Can anyone confirm if this monitor will work as 1,920 x 1,280 retina, and whether it will work scaled at 2,560 x 1,706 resolution?

For some context: The monitor is supposed to be used for software development. There are plenty of 27" 4k monitors (3,840 x 2,160 pixels) which usually show 1,920 x 1,080 as Retina display with text that is too large, and can be scaled to 2,560 x 1,440. 5K monitors that would display 2,560 x 1,440 without scaling were sold by Dell and LG for about £1,100; both stopped selling them but some are available on eBay, used. Anything larger starts at £4,000-£5,000 (Apple 6k, Dell 8k monitor), so unaffordable.

*In theory* this monitor should scale to 2,560 x 1,706 with the same 3:2 ratio which would be *very* nice for software development. But I'd rather *know* that it works, because it is quite possible that Apple only supports some small set of resolutions.

Comment: large monitor ≠ many pixels and vice versa (or rather: it doesn't need to be that way). 3840x2560 is a weird aspect ratio (3:2) for a monitor (unless maybe you do a lot of photography), however macOS/any modern OS allows different scaling options suiting the monitor, so it should work.

Comment: Tetsujin, it has the ratio that I want. I have a TV for watching videos :-) This is intended for writing code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the monitor should work as 1920x1280 Retina.

For me personally, I very much prefer such an aspect ratio. As a software developer, I have always preferred 1920x1200 (16:10) displays over the ubiquitous 1920x1080 (16:9) displays. Having a 3840x2560 (3:2) display would be even better in this regard.

If your main objective with the monitor is to view movies that are 16:9 - then of course you wouldn't really get anything extra out of this monitor compared to a standard 3840x2160 display.

Regarding the scaled 2560x1706 resolution - I haven't tested a display with this specific resolution before, so I cannot for sure say if that will work - it does sound likely that it will work. Note that the conversion is going to introduce a certain loss of "sharpness" as you're not pixel doubling, but scaling with a non-integer factor.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve bought the monitor - result: A Huawei Mateview 28.2” monitor, 3840x2560 pixels at 160 dpi, works with a 2019 Intel 16” MBP. There are about 8 resolutions from 1920x1280 to 3840x2880 available, including 2560x1707 and 2304 or 2880 wide.

The screen is 60cmx40cm. Compared to the 5k monitor on a 2015 iMac 27”, at 2560x1707 the display is 18% higher, font size is quite exactly the same, and text readability is almost as good as the iMac screen. Text quality at 2304 or 2880 wide is noticeable less good, I assume because 2560x1707 scales exactly by 50%.

Connection to the MBP is via USB-C and charges the MBP, so there is just one cable plugged in the MBP. And half the price of the 5k displays that Dell and LG don’t build anymore.